# PHP/MYSQL help for giving notifications to all users(followers) even millions of them

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

I want to make a system in PHP/MYSQL through which users of a site can follow/unfollow other users of the same site and when a user do some activity then that user's all followers should get a notification.

I know that I can create a seperate db tables called `notifications` and insert row in it for each user who needs to be notified separably like Facebook did, but i will not restrict users (i.e. on Facebook you cannot have more then 5000 friends), on my site users can follow any amount of users they wish, and if some user have 1 million followers then on my server his each and every activity will let my server down.

So how to accomplish this task, what kind of design do I need to use for my Mysql database, in what way do I need to call those rows so that i can send notifications to all followers of the user and the server also never let down.

Comment: Do you currently have a user with 1 million followers? Do you have 1 million users at all? It might be premature to think about those kinds of numbers if you're not there yet.

Comment: Yes, it can happen, please help me.

Comment: just even a user with 10,000 followers will cause my server problems. i just don't want to let the site down, i did a lot of search and thought a lot about it but still i got nothing to do with it.

Comment: I agree with Pekka, worry about this working for even 2 users. A million followers would be a nice problem to have :)

Comment: Managing 1 million users all alone would be though for even the most skiller developer. If you reach that size, you'll surely have the resources to hire help and solve this problems.

Answer (score 3):

The follower pulls the notifications from the users he follows. That way, a notification is a single row in a table. The rational is, that while I might have millions of followers, the number of people that I follow is quite small (probably less than 1000).

Also: think about a caching strategy.

Comment: hi oswald, you answer seems interesting, but the user who's following other users might be following 10K+ other users , what to do in that case?

Comment: The presumption of my answer is, that this is not the case. I just do not have the mental capacity to keep up with that many notifications. Also, I agree with what Pekka and Ryan suggested in the comment to your question: keep optimization in mind, but do it when the problem becomes imminent.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of your suggestion and the answer and comments from Oswald.

The author creates an update, which will then add records to the notifications table(s).  If the author has 10,000 followers, then there are 10,000 entries.  This will become quite large, and optimization, caching, etc... will need to be used.

The follower then connects at some interval (via a client similar to Facebook web or hand held) and pulls their notifications.  In this case, I get notifications from my last visit or all my authors. Again, this may be 10,000 rows as you indicated, but with better keys, the retrieval will be quick, since you get notifications for the follower only (their ID).  Once received, delete the pending notifications.

The second alternative would be to modify the notifications to simply have an entry for the author, and the post, and a date.  The follower connects, queries for new postings since his last search, and then filter them by author.  Try to remove as many records as possible in the first query, then attempt the filter as a second query or cached reference search.  Do not try to link both queries as you will kill the database server.  Using keys/indexes to get the smallest set first.

If the follower has a few authors, query for author updates first, then after the date.  Otherwise, search after the date then by authors.